# Visual Studio: GlobalSuppressions.cs: Prefix ~P: for attribute Target in SuppressMessage

Tags: c#, visual-studio, suppress-warnings

I suppressed several (IntelliSense) messages in Visual Studio 2017. It created entries in file `GlobalSuppressions.cs` like:

```
[assembly: System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Wrong Usage", "DisposableFixer:Undisposed ressource.", Justification = "<Pending>", Scope = "member", Target = "~M:MyProg.Class1.....Method1")]

[assembly: System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Style", "CC0001:You should use 'var' whenever possible.", Justification = "<Pending>", Scope = "member", Target = "~P:MyProg.Class2.Setter1")]
```

The prefixes `~M:` and `~P:` in attribute [`Target`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms244717.aspx) seem to be some kind of filter. What do they mean? [The only document I find about `Target`, is: "It must contain a fully-qualified item name."](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.codeanalysis.suppressmessageattribute.target(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: from what it looks like: methods and properties ...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I finally found the [documentation I was looking for](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/documentation-comments#d42-id-string-format). It reads:

> The first part of the string identifies the kind of member being documented, via a single character followed by a colon. The following kinds of members are defined:

| Character | Description |
| --- | --- |
| E | Event |
| F | Field |
| M | Method (including constructors, destructors, and operators) |
| N | Namespace |
| P | Property (including indexers) |
| T | Type (such as class, delegate, enum, interface, and struct) |
| ! | Error string; the rest of the string provides information about the error. For example, the documentation generator generates error information for links that cannot be resolved. |

I guess the first and the last entries are not relevant for suppression messages and the leading `~` is fixed by convention.

So, for example, to suppress all warnings of a given type in a whole namespace, you write:

```
[assembly: System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Style", "CC0001:You should use 'var' whenever possible.", Scope = "namespaceanddescendants", Target = "~P:MyProg.Class2.Setter1")]
```

BTW, the allowed values for `Scope` are described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.codeanalysis.suppressmessageattribute.scope?view=net-5.0):

| Value | Description |
| --- | --- |
| "member" | Suppresses warnings against a member. |
| "module" | Suppresses warnings against an assembly. It is a global suppression that applies to the entire project. |
| "namespace" | This scope suppresses warnings against the namespace itself. It does not suppress warnings against types within the namespace. |
| "namespaceanddescendants" | Suppresses warnings in a namespace and all its descendant symbols. This value is ignored by legacy code analysis. |
| "type" | Suppresses warnings against a type. |